# How to sort string with by number+characters?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have directory lists info shown below.

```
..../2mstp/zdp/b.dat:FRAME 12 9625 La 16569H  6744SI 
..../1.5mstp/zdp/d.dat:FRAME 18 9625 La 16577H  6744SI 
..../1mstp/zdp/b.dat:FRAME 11 9625 La 16577H  6744SI
..../1mstp/zdp/c.dat:FRAME 78 9625 La 16569H  6744SI
..../500kstp/zdp/a.dat:FRAME 0 9625 Fe 6744SI
..../500kstp/zdp/b.dat:FRAME 23 9625 La 15438H 6744SI
......
..../30mstp/zdp/e.dat:FRAME 0 9625 La 13469H  6744SI
```

All these info are written into a file (foo.dat) like above. I want to sort the data and remove those duplicated ones based on column 4-6, and then sort all unique data based on the first column, especially based on 500kstp, 1mstp, 1.5mstp, 2mstp,...shown below.
I used commands

`sort -unk 4,6 foo.dat |sort -nk 1 > boo.dat`

to sort and remove duplicated data. However, I could not list data based on column 1 like below.

```
..../500kstp/zdp/a.dat:FRAME 0 9625 Fe 6744SI
..../500kstp/zdp/b.dat:FRAME 23 9625 La 15438H 6744SI
..../1mstp/zdp/b.dat:FRAME 12 9625 La 16569H  6744SI 
..../1mstp/zdp/d.dat:FRAME 18 9625 La 16577H  6744SI 
......
..../30mstp/zdp/e.dat:FRAME 0 9625 La 13469H  6744SI
```

Any suggestion and help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: If you are wanting to sort by the first column then why would "**1mstp**" come before "**30mstp**"?

Comment: Before sorting, the order is random. 1mstp may be shown after 30mstp.

Comment: I tried your command on the first block of data and [I don't get the same result](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/4fef8a152d8dac0a9bb28c356ba15de7) you show.

Comment: My command can remove the duplicated data. but cannot show the sorted ones like what I  shown above. Here, my point is how to sort the data based on the column 1 after removing the duplicated data. For duplicated data, I donot have any idea to keep the smaller keywords, like keeping 1mstp instead of 1.5mstp.